# What is the Alexa skill for speaking on a schedule?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I see from links like [this](https://techwiser.com/how-to-get-alexa-to-say-what-you-want/), I can get Alexa to say arbitrary things in response to a keyword.  The problem with this is I am limited to 250 characters and have no control over her timing---she just rushes everything together.

Is there a development interface that would allow me to do something like:

1. Say text1.
2. Wait 20 seconds.
3. Say text2.
4. Wait 20 seconds.

Etc?

I imagine this is the developer interface that is commonly used for things like meditation or workout apps.  I really just need to know what to google to see what this interface is called and read docs---my searches for "Alexa Routines" "Alexa say things on a timer" return things about her skills called "routines" and "timers" not how to develop these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html): Speech Synthesis Markup Language

And you can do much more than just waiting.

```
<speak>
    There is a three second pause here <break time="3s"/>
    then the speech continues.
    <break time="3s"/>
    something else
</speak>
```

However, there is a rule where you can't allow all the break to be more than 10s.

> Break tag silence can't exceed 10 seconds, including scenarios with
> consecutive break tags. SSML with more than 10 seconds of silence
> isn't rendered to the user.

If you need to wait more than 10sec, then you can just return [your own audio](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html).

Comment: What interface calls the <speak> xml?

Comment: The [response builder](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/build-responses.html). I recommend you to follow the [tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/develop-your-first-skill.html) to have a better understanding. `handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("<speak>...</speak>")`